# Symmetrical signal with operational amplifier

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, analog, operational-amplifier

I hope you can help me. I have a project with operational amplifiers. In this project I need to create a mirror signal (symmetrical signal) from this output:

[image: output signal]

To something like this:

[image: symmetrical signal]

The two requirements are:

- Only use operational amplifiers, resistances and capacitors
- The circuit must have two inputs, a square signal and a triangular signal

I've tried with many settings, but I have not succeeded.

I created this circuit with the original output, but I don't know how can I get the mirror of a symmetrical signal:

[image: circuit created]

If someone can help me I will appreciate it.

Comment: Are you looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Inverting_amplifier to do the "mirroring"?

Comment: The simplest way is the standard inverting amplifier with G=-1… just use equal feedback resistors. By the way 20nF on the feedback of your first amp are a lot, do you need some heavy filtering?

Comment: For first signal, just add the 2 generators  ... For the second, just substract. Amplitude of square bigger than triangle. Use a more clear schematic. It help.  :) Some resistance are "too lower". Use 10k, for example. Under 15 V there is a current of 1.5 mA max. If using 500 Ohm, it can be ...30 mA ! On board, add always decoupling capacitors nearest opamp.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I could solve the problem this is the solutions. Thanks @FlorianRagwitz, LorenzoMarcantonio and Antonio51

Comment: @bisonte Would you like to post an answer to your own question to help out other people with a similar problem searching the site in the future?

Comment: Shure this is the circuit:

Comment: The two waveforms you show are mirrored in "TIME", not in amplitude. You cannot create that with any simple opamp circuit.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the problem this is the solutions:

[image: symmetri signal]

Comment: @DavideAndrea - Hi, Please look at the comments below the question. This is the OP's self-answer, no matter whether it's right or wrong. If the OP thinks it is the answer to their question, then *it is an answer*. (As usual, people can vote and/or comment about its correctness.) Also answers (including self-answers) should *not* be added into question, so it's the wrong advice to ask an OP to add their solution into the question. This is why self-answers exist, so that OPs can write their solution *as an answer*. || If you have questions on this etiquette, please ask on our [Meta]. Thanks.